# Refering to excel cells in absolute and relative terms

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have a given range as argument to a function:

```
Function wrapper(current As range)
```

now I would like to get the value of the cell that to the *far* left (Column `A`).

E.g if current cell is `H12`, I would like to get cell text which is in `A12`.

Thank you for your help

---

ok, lets leave out above problem. In general, what I want to achieve is to get a variable of Range type. In below example:

```
Function wrapper(current As range)
Set hardwarePos = Cells(current.Row, 1)
```

my hardwarePos is of type Set, and I can not pass it to another function ( GetFormula(var as Range). :

```
Function wrapper(current As range)
Set hardwarePos = Cells(current.Row, 1)
wrapper = GetFormula(hardwarePos)
```

This is not working...

---

thank's for you tips. I like the way KazJaw solved it, but stil I have some problems. Why this does not work:

```
Function wrapper(current As range)
Dim hardwarePos As range
hardwarePos = Cells(current.Row, 1)
wrapper = hardwarePos.Text
End Function
```

Comment: You could use `current.Offset(0,-1).value` to get it

Comment: Thanks, and what about absolute refferning to cells ? For e.g. given cell H12 I would like to change only the 'H' to 'A' that the result is A12 ? I can't use offset because it works in relative way.

Comment: something like this: `...= cells(current.row, 1).value`

Comment: @KazJaw worthwhile adding this as an answer.

Comment: if you don't pass the range you want directly you ought to make the function volatile and ensure you specify the sheet

Comment: as for why `.Text` does not work might be because text of a cell is in `.Value` property

Answer (score 2):

As a **formula** (without VBA)

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1))
```

With **VBA**:

```
Function wrapper(current As Range)
wrapper = Sheets(current.Parent.Name).Cells(current.Cells(1).Row, 1).Value
End Function
```

Comment: He does not want column 1/"A". He does want the column previous to current one.

Comment: and why you are not using directly current.Row?

Comment: See the other two posts by Friko - clearly Friko does want Column A

Comment: OK. I did only look at the original question.

Comment: I guess that you did understand your error and remove your -1. I will not -1 your answer, although it is not too right (you are not referring the worksheet anywhere).

Comment: Added worksheet to keep you happy, even though I think activesheet` was fine as is given the question. Whereas I do think you should answer the actual question asked, as well as ensure it handles any column :)

Comment: Thanks, you know how to make me happy. But as far as you are the one talking about solutions accounting for all the eventualities, you shouldn't deliver so weak approaches (hidden as overall-working ones). I will edit my answer a bit to account for your suggestion too :)

Comment: Possibly. But you would be on much stronger grounds if you'd actually answered the question in the first place, and robustly at that. Moving on .....

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
Public Function wrapper(current As String)
    Dim newCell As String
    newCell = Range(current).Offset(0, -1).Address

    ' Range(newCell).Select
    ' Range(newCell).value = "blabla"
End Function
```

It takes address from the current cell and uses it get the address of the previous cell in terms of columns (with `offset` function, -1 is for "one column left")

Then by using `Range(newCell)` you can do what you want with that cell, selecting, writing, ecc.

You can call wrapper with: `wapper(MyCell.Address)`

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to change the function argument from Range to String.